# How to search with the special characters in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have one App working with the dataabase in which the organisation column having the records with the special characters(single quote). I am getting force close error while searching with the special character in the text field.

The code is below:

```
    String name = idValues.getStringExtra("ORGNAME");
   String sql ="select orgname from table1 where name like '%"+ name +"%'  Order by org.name";
```

Please help me with the samplecode/links to search with the name containing special character.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using PreparedStatement .

Comment: which special characters you entered for testing this?

Comment: Since variable name contains single quote ,It would end up the sql string and make a bad sql string . SQL Injection .

Comment: Can anyone help how to replace `name like '%"+ name +"%'` statement to get the result for special character Strings?

Comment: See the answer , try it and tell us about any problem occurred .

Comment: i am using cursor to return the string sql as below :                                 `cdata = myDbHelper.getView(sql);` then how can i get the string value from prepared statement to pass to the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String name = idValues.getStringExtra("ORGNAME");    

if (name.contains("'")) {
   // Should replace all the charecters
   name = name.replaceAll("'", "''");
}

String sql ="select orgname from table1 where name like '%"+ name +"%'  Order by org.name";
```

Replace the single quote(') in the String as shown. Please try this.

Comment: Escaping left :  if(name.contains("\'"))
    {
     name.replace("\'", "");
    }

Comment: two single quotes here : name.replace("'", "''");

Comment: quotes are still not replaced , since you didn't collect the returned reference like name = name.replace("","")

Comment: I'm sorry that I have missed the assignment part. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using PreparedStatement like this :

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String sql ="select orgname from table1 where name like ? Order by orgname";
pstmt.setString(1,"%"+name+"%");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

No Error checks have been done .

Comment: i am using cursor to return the string sql as below : `cdata = myDbHelper.getView(sql);` then how can i get the string value from prepared statement to pass to the cursor?

Comment: Any specific reasons you use cursors ?  And why you write like Order by "org.name" . It should be orgname .